# Developer Story Job Status maybe a text to fix

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

As you can see, it writes:

> JOB STATUS
>
> Passive candidate interested in . Open to working remotely.

We can consider it a "bug to be fixed" just for aesthetically reasons ^^

https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/7641442?view=Cv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed, now it says *Passive candidate. Open to working remotely.* Thanks for reporting!